# Adding library to input Android C++ Visual Studio Clang exit -1

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, clang, oculus

setting up a project in MSVC 2019 C++ for Mobile dev (Android Native Activity App), if i add a library name to library dependencies in the property pages (where they are supposed to be) i get the following error:

```
Error   MSB6006 "clang.exe" exited with code 1. Android2.NativeActivity C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application 
Type\Android\3.0\Android.Common.targets 119
```

But if I instead add the library file in the solution explorer it compiles no issue...

Why is this so?

The lib trying to be added is from the Oculus SDK v 1.50.0

Thanks

Comment: Could you give  some example because they are the same thing in my Visual studio. You may have many projects and added the library to the wrong space.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT thanks but figured it out,  just added ItemGroup to the project .vcxitems xml containing the libs and it is fine now. MSFT really should fix to add .so .a libs to the linker input project configurations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added ItemGroup to the project .vcxitems xml containing the libs and it is fine now.